# adding elements from list to string array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

I have a String array like,

```
 String[] abc= new String[]{};
```

and my List has some values. I iterate the list and add each list element to string array.

```
for(int i=0; i<errList.size(); i++)
            {
                abc[i] = errList.get(i).getSrceCd();
            }
```

errList.size() has 6 values. But when the for loops executed I get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Any inputs?

Comment: your string array is declared incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a `String[]` object of zero length; so, when you try to assign an item to `abc[i]`, it is accessing an index not within your bounds `0 <= i < 0`.

You should allocate `abc` with a length instead:

```
String[] abc= new String[errList.size()];
for(int i=0; i<errList.size(); i++)
{
    abc[i] = errList.get(i).getSrceCd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to craete the string array with the same size as the list. It is not dynamic. Perhaps you can tell what you are trying to achieve with this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use for each loop which is widely used in collection framework?

Answer (score 0):

`String[] abc = errList.toArray(new String[0]);`

Or:

```
String[] abc = new String[errList.size()];    
errList.toArray(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this

```
String[] abc= errList.toArray(new String[errList.size()]);
```